# How to include tex files from different folders?

Tags: include

I have a problem in creating the math homework sheets here. What I did was creating a single folder for the math homework each day. And there are so many folder under one big folder as you can see from the picture.

[image: the math homework folder in my mac]

I want to create one main tex to create a single math work sheet that includes all the daily math homework. But I don't how to do that? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much.

And also I am looking for some videos on using the probsoln package, can someone also share the resources with me?

Appreciate your help.

Best regards

Johnny

Follow is the Minimum worked example:

In the main.tex, I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \input{SL Homework 28-March 27/2020327 SL Homework 28.tex}

\end{document}
```

But it didn't work.

In one of the daily homework, I used:

```
\documentclass[11pt, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb, algorithm, algpseudocode, multicol,epstopdf,tikz}

\usepackage[right=0.6in, left=0.6in, top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}


\begin{document} 
    \begin{questions}
        \question  The length of time, in seconds, that it takes to transfer a photograph from a camera to a computer can be modelled by a normal distribution with mean 4.7 and variance $0.7225 .$ Find the probability that a photograph can be transferred in less than 3 seconds.
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1.5in]
            $0.0228.$
        \end{solutionordottedlines}

        \question  Crates of tea should contain $200 \mathrm{kg}$, but it is known that 1 out of 45 crates, on average, is underweight.
        A sample of 630 crates is selected at random.
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item  Find the probability that more than 12 but fewer than 17 crates are underweight.
            \item Given that more than 12 but fewer than 17 crates are underweight, find the probability that more than 14 crates are underweight.
        \end{enumerate}
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1.5in]
            $(a)\ 0.408,\quad (b)\ 0.483.$
        \end{solutionordottedlines}

    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! How do your single worksheets look like? Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Hi Luki, thank you. This is my first time use MWE, It seems not so good. The idea is to include all the tex files in each daily homework folder into one main.tex so that I can create a homework exercise work sheet. Thank you so much. Just felt a bit frustrating here since I tried a methods but all failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spaces in files names in \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408787/spaces-in-files-names-in-input)

Comment: Hi Fran, thanks for the link. I tried but I didn't make it. I donn't know why.

Comment: @eaglezyj Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Did you try 
`\input{"SL Homework 28-March 27/2020327 SL Homework 28.tex"}` ?

Comment: Hi @BambOo, thank you. I tired but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you start compilation in the parent folder of `SL Homework 28-March 27` ?

Comment: Could you try the following code ? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test 1/test 1.tex}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \input{"test 1/test 1.tex"}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BambOo Thank you so much. I tried but still failed. A bit frustrated these days.

Comment: It is quite surprising that this script doesnt' work, what tex distribution / OS are you working on ?